# How can I find the average of all numbers in a textfile

Tags: vb.net, average

I'm ridiculously stuck on this one. My code below sums up all the numbers that are in the textfile `Dailyfile` and outputs the total to `AverageFile`. The problem is I don't want it to sum up. I want it to find out the `average` of all the numbers.

How can I do this?

```
Dim AverageFile As String = "C:\xxx\zzz\" & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
Dim DailyFile As String = "C:\xxx\xxx\" & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"  

            Try
                If System.IO.File.Exists(AverageFile) Then
                    Dim total As double = 0
                    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines(DailyFile)

                        total += Double.Parse(line)
                    Next
                    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(AverageFile, false)
                    objWriter.WriteLine(total.ToString) 
                    objWriter.Close()
                Else
                    'Nothing yet
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                lbErrors.Items.Add(String.Concat(TimeOfDay & " Error 98: File or folder might not exist. Restart application... ", ex.Message))
            End Try
```

The `Dailyfile` simply looks like this;

[image]

I've tried a bunch of variations on the `total 0= double.parse(line)`, because I feel like thats where the problem lies. I've also tried `diming the total as integer = 0`. I'm new to the calculating, so I don't know how things go.

Comment: Try `File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(double.Parse).Average()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average is just the total divided by the number of things you summed up. (Assuming you want to use the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Arithmetic_mean), which is probably what you are looking for.)

```
Dim total As double = 0
Dim numOfLines As Integer = 0
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines(DailyFile)
    numOfLines += 1
    total += Double.Parse(line)
Next
Dim average As Double = total / numOfLines
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(AverageFile, false)
objWriter.WriteLine(average.ToString) 
objWriter.Close()
```

What was missing in your code is just keeping track of the number of lines and dividing the sum by this number.

---

Just as an example: We are 3 people. I am 23 years old, you are 35 years old, our friend is 40 years old. The average of our ages would be `(23 + 35 + 40) / 3` which is 32.666...

Comment: Thanks, CherryDT. This is indeed just what I was missing.

Comment: A bit late to come with this, but is there any small adjustments to this so that I only get for example 32 as output instead of 32.666?

Comment: If you really want to round down always (like in your example), you can use `Math.floor(average)` instead of `average` at the end (e.g. `objWriter.WriteLine(Math.floor(average).ToString)`). If you want to use banker's rounding (i.e. 32.4 would become 32, but 32.6 would become 33), use `Math.round(average, 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Either use [CherryDT's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937171/284240) to count the lines and divide the total through this number or use LINQ's `Enumerable.Average`, for example with this concise query:

```
Dim allNumbers = From line In IO.File.ReadLines(DailyFile)
                 Let num = line.TryGetDouble()
                 Where num.HasValue
                 Select num.Value
Dim average As Double = allNumbers.Average()
```

I've used following [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514025.aspx) to try-parse the string to a `Nullable(Of Double)`:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function TryGetDouble(ByVal str As String) As Nullable(Of Double)
        If str Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Dim d As Double
        If Double.TryParse(str.Trim(), d) Then
            Return d
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and going in such detail, Tim. I'm grabing the knownledge you're handing me and I'll explore the possibilities with this.